# Undefined variable: $sameday at somthing.php

Tags: php, error-handling

i m write this code on something.php for featured event

```
$day_start = date("j", mktime(0,0,0,$event_start_month, $event_start_day, $event_start_year));

$day_end = date("j", mktime(0,0,0, $event_end_month, $event_end_day, $event_end_year));



        if (($day_start == $day_end)) {
            $same_day = true;
        }
        <?php if ($same_day == false) { ?>
<span class="value value-date"> - <?php echo $day_end; ?></span>
```

when i echo this

```
<?php if ($same_day == false) { ?>
<span class="value value-date"> - <?php echo $day_end; ?></span>
```

the error is occurred

```
Error Processing Feed: Undefined variable: same_day at something.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign something to `$same_day` always to avoid this warning. Like this:

```
if (($day_start == $day_end)) {
        $same_day = true;
    } else{
        $same_day =false; // <-- This is the new part.
    }
...
if ($same_day == false) {
```

Otherwise it is only a notice. But cleaner to handle it properly

Or maybe simpler to not introduce the new variable. Use only `($day_start == $day_end)` in the second if and omit the first one completely.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to avoid error

```
$same_day = false;

if (($day_start == $day_end)) {
        $same_day = true;
    } 

......

 <?php if ($same_day == false) { ?>
            <?php echo $day_end; ?>
```